# PHP CMS like Wordpress Pods

Tags: php, content-management-system, wordpress, podscms

I am looking for a CMS in PHP just like the wordpress plugin called Pods. I've been searching for a long time but i can't find any results that suits what i'm asking. Does anybody know a CMS like this?

Greetings,

Peter

Comment: WordPress is a CMS written in PHP... And if Pods is a plugin for WordPress is written in PHP to...

Comment: Yes but i don't want to use Wordpress.

Comment: What's wrong with WordPress?? If you don't want to use it, try Drupal...

Comment: Does drupal support the same functionality as Pods?

Comment: Ok, what you are lookin for is a plugin to change functionality without coding, not a CMS. I don't know if you can do that without coding in Drupal, I don't think so

Comment: I don't think you understand what i mean (i'm from Holland so sorry for my bad English) but im looking for a CMS that works just like the Wordpress plugin Pods. So that you can add custom field types etc.

Comment: Drupal has CCK built right into it, so.. yeah Drupal or something like ExpressionEngine could work for your needs there. I still don't understand why you wouldn't use WP+Pods, if you like it that much.